# Ejabberd: Crash Dump during installation

Tags: ubuntu, xmpp, ejabberd

Yesterday I tried to install Ejabberd first through souce code, and then with Ubuntu specific packages.
I guess I made a mess, because now I'm getting this threatening `Crash dump` error.

```
(base) marco@pc01:~$ sudo aptitude install ejabberd
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ejabberd erlang-asn1{a} erlang-base{a} erlang-base64url{a} 
  erlang-crypto{a} erlang-edoc{a} erlang-fs-listener{a} erlang-goldrush{a} 
  erlang-inets{a} erlang-jiffy{a} erlang-jose{a} erlang-lager{a} 
  erlang-mnesia{a} erlang-odbc{a} erlang-os-mon{a} erlang-p1-cache-tab{a} 
  erlang-p1-eimp{a} erlang-p1-iconv{a} erlang-p1-stringprep{a} 
  erlang-p1-tls{a} erlang-p1-utils{a} erlang-p1-xml{a} erlang-p1-xmpp{a} 
  erlang-p1-yaml{a} erlang-p1-zlib{a} erlang-proper{a} erlang-public-key{a} 
  erlang-runtime-tools{a} erlang-snmp{a} erlang-ssl{a} 
  erlang-syntax-tools{a} erlang-xmerl{a} inotify-tools{a} 
  libinotifytools0{a} libodbc1{a} libsctp1{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 36 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/22,9 MB of archives. After unpacking 40,9 MB will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] Y
Extracting templates from packages: 100% 
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 395356 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-erlang-base_1%3a20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking erlang-base (1:20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package erlang-asn1.
Preparing to unpack .../01-erlang-asn1_1%3a20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking erlang-asn1 (1:20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package erlang-crypto.
Preparing to unpack .../02-erlang-crypto_1%3a20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking erlang-crypto (1:20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package erlang-mnesia.
Preparing to unpack .../03-erlang-mnesia_1%3a20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking erlang-mnesia (1:20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package erlang-runtime-tools.
Preparing to unpack .../04-erlang-runtime-tools_1%3a20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking erlang-runtime-tools (1:20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package erlang-public-key.
Preparing to unpack .../05-erlang-public-key_1%3a20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking erlang-public-key (1:20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package erlang-ssl.
Preparing to unpack .../06-erlang-ssl_1%3a20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking erlang-ssl (1:20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package erlang-inets.
Preparing to unpack .../07-erlang-inets_1%3a20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking erlang-inets (1:20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libodbc1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../08-libodbc1_2.3.4-1.1ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libodbc1:amd64 (2.3.4-1.1ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package erlang-odbc.
Preparing to unpack .../09-erlang-odbc_1%3a20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking erlang-odbc (1:20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package erlang-syntax-tools.
Preparing to unpack .../10-erlang-syntax-tools_1%3a20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking erlang-syntax-tools (1:20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libinotifytools0.
Preparing to unpack .../11-libinotifytools0_3.14-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libinotifytools0 (3.14-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package inotify-tools.
Preparing to unpack .../12-inotify-tools_3.14-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking inotify-tools (3.14-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package erlang-fs-listener.
Preparing to unpack .../13-erlang-fs-listener_4.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking erlang-fs-listener (4.1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package erlang-xmerl.
Preparing to unpack .../14-erlang-xmerl_1%3a20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking erlang-xmerl (1:20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package erlang-proper.
Preparing to unpack .../15-erlang-proper_1.2+git988ea0ed9f+dfsg-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking erlang-proper (1.2+git988ea0ed9f+dfsg-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package erlang-jiffy.
Preparing to unpack .../16-erlang-jiffy_0.14.11+dfsg-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking erlang-jiffy (0.14.11+dfsg-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package erlang-base64url.
Preparing to unpack .../17-erlang-base64url_1.0-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking erlang-base64url (1.0-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package erlang-jose.
Preparing to unpack .../18-erlang-jose_1.8.4-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking erlang-jose (1.8.4-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package erlang-goldrush.
Preparing to unpack .../19-erlang-goldrush_0.1.9-4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking erlang-goldrush (0.1.9-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package erlang-lager.
Preparing to unpack .../20-erlang-lager_3.5.2-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking erlang-lager (3.5.2-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package erlang-snmp.
Preparing to unpack .../21-erlang-snmp_1%3a20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking erlang-snmp (1:20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package erlang-os-mon.
Preparing to unpack .../22-erlang-os-mon_1%3a20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking erlang-os-mon (1:20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package erlang-edoc.
Preparing to unpack .../23-erlang-edoc_1%3a20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking erlang-edoc (1:20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package erlang-p1-utils.
Preparing to unpack .../24-erlang-p1-utils_1.0.10-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking erlang-p1-utils (1.0.10-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package erlang-p1-cache-tab.
Preparing to unpack .../25-erlang-p1-cache-tab_1.0.12-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking erlang-p1-cache-tab (1.0.12-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package erlang-p1-eimp.
Preparing to unpack .../26-erlang-p1-eimp_1.0.2-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking erlang-p1-eimp (1.0.2-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package erlang-p1-iconv.
Preparing to unpack .../27-erlang-p1-iconv_1.0.6-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking erlang-p1-iconv (1.0.6-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package erlang-p1-stringprep.
Preparing to unpack .../28-erlang-p1-stringprep_1.0.10-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking erlang-p1-stringprep (1.0.10-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package erlang-p1-tls.
Preparing to unpack .../29-erlang-p1-tls_1.0.20-1ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking erlang-p1-tls (1.0.20-1ubuntu0.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package erlang-p1-xml.
Preparing to unpack .../30-erlang-p1-xml_1.1.28-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking erlang-p1-xml (1.1.28-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package erlang-p1-xmpp.
Preparing to unpack .../31-erlang-p1-xmpp_1.1.19-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking erlang-p1-xmpp (1.1.19-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package erlang-p1-yaml.
Preparing to unpack .../32-erlang-p1-yaml_1.0.12-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking erlang-p1-yaml (1.0.12-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package erlang-p1-zlib.
Preparing to unpack .../33-erlang-p1-zlib_1.0.3-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking erlang-p1-zlib (1.0.3-2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../34-ejabberd_18.01-2_amd64.deb ...
Generating SSL certificate /etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.pem...
Unpacking ejabberd (18.01-2) ...
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/opt/ejabberd-21.04/logs': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/opt/ejabberd-21.04': Directory not empty
Selecting previously unselected package libsctp1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../35-libsctp1_1.0.17+dfsg-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsctp1:amd64 (1.0.17+dfsg-2) ...
Processing triggers for ufw (0.36-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Setting up libinotifytools0 (3.14-2) ...
Setting up libodbc1:amd64 (2.3.4-1.1ubuntu3) ...
Setting up inotify-tools (3.14-2) ...
Setting up erlang-base (1:20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2) ...
Searching for services which depend on erlang and should be started...none found.
Setting up libsctp1:amd64 (1.0.17+dfsg-2) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot 
Setting up erlang-xmerl (1:20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up erlang-crypto (1:20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up erlang-asn1 (1:20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up erlang-mnesia (1:20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.4) ...
Setting up erlang-base64url (1.0-2) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.46) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up erlang-runtime-tools (1:20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up erlang-syntax-tools (1:20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up erlang-odbc (1:20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up erlang-proper (1.2+git988ea0ed9f+dfsg-1) ...
Setting up erlang-fs-listener (4.1-1) ...
Setting up erlang-p1-zlib (1.0.3-2) ...
Setting up erlang-jiffy (0.14.11+dfsg-2) ...
Setting up erlang-public-key (1:20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up erlang-snmp (1:20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up erlang-ssl (1:20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up erlang-inets (1:20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up erlang-goldrush (0.1.9-4) ...
Setting up erlang-jose (1.8.4-2) ...
Setting up erlang-os-mon (1:20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up erlang-edoc (1:20.2.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up erlang-lager (3.5.2-2) ...
Setting up erlang-p1-utils (1.0.10-2) ...
Setting up erlang-p1-stringprep (1.0.10-2) ...
Setting up erlang-p1-yaml (1.0.12-2) ...
Setting up erlang-p1-iconv (1.0.6-2) ...
Setting up erlang-p1-tls (1.0.20-1ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up erlang-p1-cache-tab (1.0.12-2) ...
Setting up erlang-p1-xml (1.1.28-1) ...
Setting up erlang-p1-eimp (1.0.2-2) ...
Setting up erlang-p1-xmpp (1.1.19-1) ...
Setting up ejabberd (18.01-2) ...


(base) marco@pc01:~$ ejabberdctl
{"init terminating in [do_boot",{undef,[{ejabberd_ctl,start,[],[]},{init,start_em,1,[]},{init,do_boot,3,[]}]}}](url)
init terminating in do_boot ({undef,[{ejabberd_ctl,start,[],[]},{init,start_em,1,[]},{init,do_boot,3,[]}]})

Crash dump is being written to: /usr/local/var/log/ejabberd/erl_crash_20210427-084312.dump...done
```

This is the complete dump file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PkEQkx0aWO8MsuvZiA8NVfl8uLluTzQc/view?usp=sharing

```
O.S: Ubuntu 18.04.4. Deskotp
Erlang Version: 

  cat /usr/lib/erlang/releases/RELEASES
 %% coding: utf-8
  [{release,"Erlang/OTP","20","9.2",
      [{kernel,"5.4.1","/usr/lib/erlang/lib/kernel-5.4.1"},
       {stdlib,"3.4.3","/usr/lib/erlang/lib/stdlib-3.4.3"},
       {sasl,"3.1.1","/usr/lib/erlang/lib/sasl-3.1.1"}],
```

How to recover from this bad error `Crash dump` in order to restart from scratch the installation?
Looking forward to your kind help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yesterday I tried to install Ejabberd first through souce code

Just curiosity: what problems did you find, that prefered to use the Ubuntu package?

Did you **install** from source code? If so, did you later **uninstall** it? Maybe uninstallation left some files there (there was some bug related to that in *make uninstall*)... it will help if you can take a look at the installation paths and remove the remaining ejabberd files and directories, specially the file *ejabberdctl*.

> and then with Ubuntu specific packages

Well, it could be that both installations get mixed... or maybe the Ubuntu package has some problem unrelated to your previous installation. Keep all investigation lines open :)

> {"init terminating in [do_boot",{undef,[{ejabberd_ctl,start,[],

This error message says that erlang cannot find the file *ejabberd_ctl.beam*, or that the file doesn't define the function *start*.

Just a wild idea: maybe you are running the "ejabberdctl" script from source installation (pointing to the old ejabberd beam files), but now you have the ejabberd beam files installed in a different location (by the Ubuntu package).

Comment: I removed all the `ejabberd folders` I found. Do you suggest me to re-install it from source code or from Ubuntu package repo?

Comment: If the ejabberd version provided in Ubuntu is recent enough for you, use that one.

Comment: Thanks to your indications, I re-installed `ejabberd` from source, using Erlange version 21.2 and now it works fine. Thank you @Badlop